# Searching for a drawing applet to use in Mediawiki?

Tags: 12.04, image-editor, mediawiki

I am searching for a drawing applet which I can use in my mediawiki (v. 1.21.1 newest stable) . For now I found 2 extensions. ( I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server and the common PHP Mediawiki)

```
anywikidraw
svgedit
```

I made SVGEdit run on my wiki, but it is not working well, and not good to use. Anywikidraw is not supported for my verison.

So are there any other drawing tools which I can use in my wiki ?

I want to draw something into an existing picture (jpg jped png whatever) and directly save it! I don't want to download a picture first and then paint it an reupload.

If anyone finds a working solution i will upvote and accept immediately. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found on the [Category:Image_extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aImage_extensions) on [the MediaWiki official site](http://www.mediawiki.org/):

- [EditImage](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aEditImage) - provides simple image editing functionality to every users within a browser. (Javascript + ImageMagick)
- [Painting](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPainting) - allows bitmap collaborative drawing. (Java applet)

Comment: thanks ignis, I will check this on the weekend. We have some issues here and I don't have the time to check now. If we like something of these 2, you get your snickers. regards

Comment: so, the first one i already knew. It just supports 'cropping', the second one is outdated. so i can't use any of them.